# How to find out the trend of the dataset using python. Whether the trend is increasing or decreasing with respect to time and date?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, trend

I am new to Python and I have a dataset like this:

```
Date    Y
12/16/2013 7:00 104052
12/16/2013 15:00    103213
12/16/2013 23:00    104724
12/17/2013 7:00 104257
12/17/2013 15:00    105565
12/17/2013 23:00    103970
12/18/2013 7:00 104026
12/18/2013 15:00    103532
12/18/2013 23:00    101313
12/19/2013 7:00 105233
12/19/2013 15:00    105864
12/19/2013 23:00    105621
12/20/2013 7:00 108011
12/20/2013 15:00    108263
12/20/2013 23:00    107320
12/21/2013 7:00 106211
12/21/2013 15:00    106315
12/21/2013 23:00    104821
12/22/2013 7:00 106312
12/22/2013 15:00    107649
12/22/2013 23:00    107690
12/23/2013 7:00 107274
12/23/2013 15:00    107298
12/23/2013 23:00    107059
```

How to find the trend of Y with respect to date and time with the above data ?

I tried this code:

```
def trend(csvfile):
filename = csvfile

data = read_csv(filename)

dateparse = lambda dates: datetime.strptime(dates, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M')
data = read_csv(filename, parse_dates=True, index_col = 'Date', date_parser= dateparse)

ts = data['Y']

def test_stationarity(timeseries):

    rolmean = rolling_mean(timeseries, window=12)
    rolstd = rolling_std(timeseries, window=12)

    orig = plt.plot(timeseries, color='blue', label='Original')
    mean = plt.plot(rolmean, color='red', label='Rolling Mean')
    std = plt.plot(rolstd, color='black', label='Rolling std')
    plt.legend(loc='best')
    plt.title('Rolling Mean & Standard deviation')
    plt.show()


    print 'Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:'
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
        dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
    print dfoutput


test_stationarity(ts)
```

trend("Data_Analysis_Sample.csv")

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: You need to provide extra information: What is the format of the dataset? what sort of trend you wish to find?

Comment: I'm pleased to hear that you want to find the trend of a dataset with Python. Have fun.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 , Thanks for replying. I said I am new to "PYTHON". If you think its funny then i am happy that you laughed atleast  :)

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, i want know whether the trend is increasing or decreasing with respect to time and date. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Dheeraj: I have the answer code with me, alas the question was put on hold before I was able to post it. Please explain your question a bit more to reopen it.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, Unable to do that. What can i do?

Comment: It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (output, tracebacks, etc.). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive. Check the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: @TigerhawkT3, i have uploaded my sample code what i have tried so far.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, i have uploaded a my code. please have a look.

Comment: Just for your need, I'll give the code here and move it to answer post as soon as this post (hopefully) opens: `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt\n
import numpy as np\n data = [] \n with open('testData.txt') as f:\n for line in f:\n rec = line.split();\n data.append([rec[0]+' '+rec[1]]+[int(rec[2])])\n data = np.array(data)\n plt.plot(data[:,1])\n plt.show()`
replace \n with newline; hope you could get the indents right. I stored your dataset presentation in a file named testData.txt just by copy-pasting. The output is a graph where you could notice the increasing and decreasing in time.

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac, Thanks for your help. Will try the code and get back to you soon.